# How to increase the max values of color range in heatmap.2()

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have the following code:

```
my_palette <- colorRampPalette(rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")))(n = 50)
par(mar = c(7, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
gplots::heatmap.2(as.matrix(mtcars),
  Colv = TRUE,
  Rowv = TRUE,
  col = my_palette,
  density.info = "none",
  key = TRUE,
  scale = "none",
  ylab = "Y_LABEL",
  xlab = "X_LABEL",
  trace = "none",
  margins = c(12, 8))
```

It produces this plot:

[image]

Note there that the reddest color in the color key corresponds to max values of `mtcars` which is 472.

Is there a way to increase that max values to 1000 so that the color range in the heatmap span from 0 to 1000?

With that scheme, the cell with value 472 would be much less red or even blue or white.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to specify the `breaks` you are using for colors manually (see last line):

```
# NOTE: starting from R v3.6.0 base has palettes, so you don't need RColorBrewer
my_palette <- hcl.colors(64, palette="RdBu", rev=TRUE)

par(mar = c(7, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
gplots::heatmap.2(as.matrix(mtcars),
                  Colv = TRUE,
                  Rowv = TRUE,
                  col = my_palette,
                  density.info = "none",
                  key = TRUE,
                  scale = "none",
                  ylab = "Y_LABEL",
                  xlab = "X_LABEL",
                  trace = "none",
                  margins = c(12, 8),
                  breaks=seq(0,1000,1000/length(my_palette)))
```

[image: heatmap]